# How to animate SVG fill and path in a similar style to vivus.js

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, vivus

I am trying to animate an SVG with `vivus.js` but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Vivus seems to be able to read the SVG correctly, I can run the following code:

```
var test = new Vivus('welcome_message', {duration: 200});
console.table(test.map);
```

And get the following result in the console (this is how vivus recommends you debug it):

```
(index) el    startAt             duration            progress
0       path  0                   133.33333333333331  0.0075000000000000015
1       path  5.555555555555556   133.33333333333331  0
2       path  11.111111111111112  133.33333333333331  0
3       path  16.666666666666668  133.33333333333331  0
4       path  22.222222222222225  133.33333333333331  0
5       path  27.777777777777782  133.33333333333331  0
6       path  33.333333333333336  133.33333333333331  0
7       path  38.88888888888889   133.33333333333331  0
8       path  44.44444444444445   133.33333333333331  0
9       path  50.00000000000001   133.33333333333331  0
10      path  55.555555555555564  133.33333333333331  0
11      path  61.11111111111112   133.33333333333331  0
12      path  66.66666666666667   133.33333333333331  0
```

This says to me the vivus is working, but when the code runs, nothing happens.

Please see the following very simple jsfiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/zzgnkwtn/2/

All I can thinks is that perhaps there is something wrong with my SVGs but seeing as it is picking up on the paths correctly this doesn't seem right.

Here is a link to the vivus documentation incase anyone wants to have a look, I am stumped.

https://github.com/maxwellito/vivus#vivusjs

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

(changed title from 'SVG animation with vivus.js not working' to 'How to animate SVG fill and path in a similar style to vivus.js')

I have realised that the end goal I am trying to achieve isn't actually the above question, this is because I am new to SVG animation and started on the wrong path.

What I am more looking to achieve is something like the following tutorial:
  https://medium.com/@gordonnl/stylised-line-animations-ded23320ffe5#.v6va1kc1w

The key difference and the main thing I am struggling is I want that exact type of animation but I want to animate the `fill` and the path, not just the path.

With help from @Alvin I have realised that some kind of `clipPath` or `mask` is required, I have tried to do this by following the above tutorial but this is the result I am getting:
  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMeQLB

This seems to animate some of the paths but it is definitely not doing what I want.

Any help from anyone would be amazing!

**FINAL RESULT**

I finally managed to achieve what I was trying to do, most of the problem is that the SVG was not crated in the best way for animation in Illustrator, I needed to convert my object into a `Compound Path` so I could use it as `clipPath` and then have a simple path underneath which I can easily animate.

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqjyzX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my demo, click on blue circle to restart animation.

```js
var sign = new Vivus('mySign', {
    type: 'scenario-sync',
    duration: 20,
    start: 'autostart',
    dashGap: 20,
    forceRender: false
  },
  function() {
    if (window.console) {
      console.log('Animation finished. [log triggered from callback]');
    }
    $('#mySign').find('path').attr('class', 'fill_path');
  });

function runme() {
  $('#mySign').find('path').attr('class', '');
  sign.reset().play();
};
```

```css
svg * {
 stroke: blue;
 stroke-width: 1;
 fill: none;
}
.fill_path {
 fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/vivus/latest/vivus.min.js"></script>

<svg id="mySign" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve"  >

      <path data-duration="30" d="M27.9,9.6c0,0,0.2,1.1,0.4,2.7c0.1,0.4,0.2,1.1,0,1.6c-0.2,0.6-0.7,0.8-1.1,0.9c-0.4,0.1-1,0.1-1.3-0.2c-0.7,0.7-0.6,0.6-1.1,0.7c0,0-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.1c-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1c-0.6,0.1-0.9-1-1-1.4c-0.3-1.4-0.6-2.8-0.9-4.2C22.2,9.5,22,9,22,8.9c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.7c0.1,0,0.4-0.1,0.5-0.1c0.4-0.1,0.5,0.1,0.6,0.5c0.4,1.5,0.7,3,1.1,4.5c0.1,0.2,0.4,1.4,0.9,1.3c0.3-0.1,0.1-1.1,0.1-1.3c-0.2-0.8-0.3-1.6-0.5-2.4c-0.1-0.8-0.2-1.5-0.4-2.3c-0.2-0.7-0.1-0.8,0.3-0.9c0.2,0,0.6,0,0.6,0.2c0,0,0,0.4,0,0.4c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.6c0.3,1.4,0.6,2.9,0.8,4.3c0.1,0.4,0.6,1,1.1,0.9c0.4-0.1,0.1-2,0.1-2.1c0-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6c0,0-0.1-1.3-0.2-2c-0.1-0.7-0.2-1.3-0.4-1.9C26.8,7.1,27.4,7,27.4,7c0.3-0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.2C27.8,8,27.9,8.8,27.9,9.6z"></path>
      <path data-duration="30" d="M32.3,9.4c-0.1,0-0.8,0.1-0.9,0.1c-0.3,0-0.6,0.1-0.8,0.1c0.2,1.1,0.4,2.2,0.6,3.2c0.4-0.1,0.9-0.2,1.3-0.2c0.1,0,0.3,0,0.4,0c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.7,0.3,0.9c0.1,0.4-0.1,0.3-0.4,0.4c-0.1,0-0.7,0.1-0.8,0.1c-0.5,0.1-1,0.2-1.5,0.3c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.2c0-0.2,0-0.1,0-0.4c-0.2-1-0.4-2.1-0.6-3.1c-0.2-0.9-0.3-1.9-0.5-2.8C29.1,7.4,29,7.1,29,6.8c0.3-0.1,0.7-0.2,1.1-0.3c0.5-0.1,1-0.2,1.5-0.3c0.3-0.1,0.5,0.8,0.5,1c0,0-0.3,0.2-0.3,0.2c-0.4,0-0.8,0.1-1.2,0.1c-0.3,0.1-0.3,0-0.3,0.3c0,0,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.7c0.2,0.1,0.3,0,0.6,0c1.3-0.2,1.4-0.3,1.5,0.5C32.6,9.1,32.5,9.3,32.3,9.4z"></path>
      <path data-duration="30" d="M36.6,13.2c-0.5,0.1-1.6,0.4-1.7,0.4c-0.2,0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2c-0.3-2.4-0.7-4.8-1-7.1c0,0-0.2-0.4,0.1-0.5c1.1-0.2,1.2-0.4,1.3,0.7c0,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.1,1c0,0.1,0,0.4,0,0.5c0.2,1.1,0.4,2.2,0.5,3.3c0.1,0.1,0,0.7,0.2,0.6c0.1,0,0.5-0.1,0.5-0.1c0.2,0,0.4,1.2,0.4,1.2C36.8,13,36.7,13.1,36.6,13.2z"></path>
      <path data-duration="30" d="M39.4,6.9c-0.3,0.6-0.5,1.2-0.6,1.7c0,0.2-0.1,0.5-0.1,0.7c0,0.1,0,1,0,1.2c0.1,0.8,0.6,1.3,1.5,1.2c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0.3,0,0.5,0.8,0.5,0.9c0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.2c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0c-0.1,0-0.5,0-0.7-0.1c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.3,0c-1.4-0.4-1.6-1.3-1.7-2c0,0-0.1-1-0.1-1.4c0-0.4,0.1-1.3,0.2-1.9c0-0.1,1-2.3,1.7-2.4c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2,0.1c0.1,0.3,0.2,0.6,0.2,0.6C40.1,5.7,39.6,6.5,39.4,6.9z"></path>
      <path data-duration="30" d="M43.9,12.4c-1.5,0.1-2.2-2.5-2.2-3.1c0-0.4-0.1-0.7-0.1-1.1c0-0.1,0.1-0.7,0.1-1c0.1-1.4,0.9-3,2.4-3.1c0.6-0.1,1.3,0.6,1.6,1.1c0.6,1,0.8,2.1,0.9,3.2C46.5,10.1,46.2,12.2,43.9,12.4z M44.5,5.7c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.7-0.5c-1,0.1-1.2,3.1-1.1,3.6c0,0.2,0.3,2.7,1.4,2.6c0.3,0,0.7-0.4,0.9-0.7c0.5-0.8,0.5-1.6,0.4-2.3C45.3,7.7,45,6.2,44.5,5.7z"></path>
      <path data-duration="30" d="M55.1,11.9c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6-0.1c-0.3-1.1-0.4-1.5-0.5-2.3c-0.2-0.9-0.4-1.9-0.6-2.8c0,0,0,0,0,0c-0.4,1.2-1,3.3-1.3,5c-0.1,0.1-0.9,0.3-1.1,0.3c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0c-0.4-1.3-0.9-2.9-1.3-4.3c-0.3,1.1-0.3,2.5-0.6,4.2c0,0-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.1c-0.4,0-0.2,0-1,0.1c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2c0,0,0.1-0.9,0.1-1.4c0.1-0.8,0.4-3.4,0.5-4.8c0-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5c0-0.1,0-1,0.3-1c0.3,0,1.1,0.1,1.1,0.1c0.5,1.5,0.9,3.1,1.6,5c0,0,0,0,0,0c0.5-1.7,1.1-3.5,1.4-4.4C52.8,4.6,53,4.3,53,4.1C53.1,4,53.8,4,53.9,4c0.4,0,0.5,1,0.5,1.4c0.1,0.3,0.2,0.7,0.2,1.1c0.1,0.3,0.2,0.9,0.2,1.3c0.1,0.6,0.3,1.4,0.4,2.2c0.1,0.4,0.4,1.4,0.4,1.5C55.8,11.9,55.2,11.8,55.1,11.9z"></path>
      <path data-duration="30" d="M59.7,7.2c-0.1,0-0.8-0.1-0.9-0.1c-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.8,0c0,1.1,0,2.2,0,3.3c0.5,0,0.9,0,1.4,0c0.1,0,0.3,0,0.4,0.1c0,0.1,0.1,0.7,0.1,0.9c0,0.4-0.2,0.3-0.5,0.3c-0.1,0-0.7-0.1-0.8-0.1c-0.5,0-1,0-1.6,0c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3c0-0.2,0-0.1,0-0.4c0-1.1,0-2.1,0-3.2c0-0.9,0-1.9,0-2.8c0-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.9C57.3,4,57.7,4,58.1,4c0.5,0,1,0,1.5,0c0.3,0,0.3,0.9,0.3,1c0,0-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.1c-0.4,0-0.8-0.1-1.2-0.1C58.1,5,58,4.9,58,5.3c0,0,0,0.5,0,0.7c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1C60,6.1,60,6,60,6.9C60,7,59.9,7.2,59.7,7.2z"></path>
      <path data-duration="30" d="M68.6,5.4c-0.4,0-0.9-0.1-1.3-0.1c-0.1,1.9-0.2,3.8-0.4,5.7c0,0.1,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.7c0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.2c-0.2,0-0.7,0-0.8,0c-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.6-0.1-0.8c0.1-1.5,0.2-3.1,0.3-4.6c0.1-1.4,0.2-0.9-1.7-1.2c0-0.1-0.1-0.7-0.1-0.8c0,0,0-0.2,0.1-0.3c1.1,0.1,2.1,0.1,3.2,0.2c0.4,0,1.3,0.1,1.7,0.1c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0,0.4C69.1,5.1,69.1,5.4,68.6,5.4z"></path>
      <path data-duration="30" d="M71.6,12.5C70.1,12.3,69.9,9.6,70,9c0-0.4,0.1-0.7,0.1-1.1c0-0.1,0.2-0.7,0.2-1c0.3-1.4,1.4-2.8,2.9-2.6c0.6,0.1,1.2,0.9,1.4,1.4C74.9,6.8,75,7.9,74.8,9C74.7,10.6,73.9,12.7,71.6,12.5z M73.5,6c-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.6-0.6-0.7c-1-0.1-1.7,2.8-1.8,3.4c0,0.2-0.2,2.7,0.9,2.8c0.3,0,0.8-0.3,1-0.6c0.6-0.7,0.7-1.5,0.8-2.2C73.9,8.1,73.9,6.5,73.5,6z"></path>
      <path data-duration="30" d="M83.6,7.2c-0.4-0.1-0.9-0.1-1.3-0.2c-0.3,1.9-0.6,3.8-0.9,5.6c0,0.1,0,0.6,0,0.7c0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2c-0.2,0-0.7,0-0.8,0c-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2c0-0.1,0-0.6,0-0.8c0.2-1.5,0.5-3.1,0.7-4.6c0.2-1.4,0.3-0.8-1.6-1.3c0-0.1,0-0.7,0-0.8c0,0,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3c1,0.2,2.1,0.3,3.1,0.5c0.4,0.1,1.3,0.2,1.6,0.3c0,0.1,0,0.3,0,0.4C84.1,7,84,7.3,83.6,7.2z"></path>
      <path data-duration="30" d="M87.8,14.4c0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.2c-0.1,0.1-0.8,0.1-1,0c-0.2,0-0.2-0.3-0.1-0.4c0.2-0.8,0.4-1.6,0.6-2.4c0.1-0.5,0.2-0.9,0.3-1.4c-0.4-0.1-0.9-0.2-1.3-0.2c-0.1,0.6-0.2,1.3-0.4,1.9c0,0,0,0.4,0,0.4c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.7c0,0.1,0,0.6-0.1,0.6c0,0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.2c-0.1,0-0.6-0.1-0.6-0.1C84.2,14,84,14,84.3,13.4c0.4-2.1,0.7-4.2,1.1-6.2c0-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.7c0.1,0,0.3-0.1,0.3,0c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0.1,0,0.4,0.1,0.4,0.2c0.1,0.5-0.1,1.2-0.2,1.8c0,0.2-0.1,0.5-0.1,0.8c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.2c0.9,0.2,0.9,0.2,1-0.3c0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.8c0-0.1,0.1-0.9,0.2-1.3c0.1,0,0.3,0,0.4,0c0.2,0,0.8,0.2,0.6,0.6C88.7,9.9,88.3,12.1,87.8,14.4z"></path>
      <path data-duration="30" d="M92.7,11.3c-0.1,0-0.8-0.2-0.8-0.3c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.1-0.8-0.2c-0.2,1.1-0.5,2.1-0.7,3.2c0.4,0.1,0.9,0.2,1.3,0.3c0.1,0,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2c0,0.1-0.1,0.7-0.1,0.9c-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.3-0.5,0.2c-0.1,0-0.7-0.2-0.7-0.2c-0.5-0.1-1-0.2-1.5-0.3c0-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.3c0-0.2,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.4c0.2-1,0.5-2.1,0.7-3.1c0.2-0.9,0.4-1.8,0.6-2.8c0-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.9c0.4,0,0.7,0.1,1.1,0.1c0.5,0.1,1,0.2,1.5,0.3c0.3,0.1,0.1,1,0.1,1.1c0,0-0.3,0-0.4,0c-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.2-1.1-0.3c-0.3-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4,0.2c0,0-0.1,0.5-0.1,0.7c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.2c1.3,0.3,1.4,0.3,1.2,1.1C93.1,11.2,92.9,11.4,92.7,11.3z"></path>

 <path transform="translate(-270,30)" data-duration="30" d="M324.6,61.2c16.6,0,29.5-12.9,29.5-29.5c0-16.6-12.9-29.5-29.5-29.5c-16.6,0-29.5,12.9-29.5,29.5C295.1,48.4,308,61.2,324.6,61.2z" onclick="runme();" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, I have been playing around with your example and you have certainly got it working. I am hoping you can help me to get this to work in the way I want to as the animation that is currently happening is not actually my end goal. I am hoping that the fill colour can be animated too, the stroke is being animated which is great but I am hoping the whole thing can be drawn in like the Vivus examples, please see my new fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/zzgnkwtn/4/

Comment: Vivus uses dash-array animation that works on `<path...` but not the `fill` CSS. See discussion on [vivus forum fill code](https://github.com/maxwellito/vivus/issues/21) and [some suggestions](https://github.com/maxwellito/vivus/issues/71)

Comment: Another [vivus forum](https://github.com/maxwellito/vivus/issues/49) discussion where users ask about `fill` on icons (which is **not** supported by vivus)

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back to me so quickly, and thanks for your help, opacity animations are nice but unfortunately its not what im looking for. I don't even know if what I am looking for is possible but, is there a way of drawing in the fill from top to bottom or something in the same way that the stroke animations work? Thanks again.

Comment: Perhaps I need to look at using a different library

Comment: You can use SVG masks & clippath, see my example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188696/change-the-fill-of-an-svg-as-a-progress-bar-passes-in-the-background/26189303 (scroll down to see aimation in the demo)

Comment: clipPath and masks are definately the way i need to go, although I don't think vivus.js is going to be able to do what i need any more. I have been looking at this tutorial https://medium.com/@gordonnl/stylised-line-animations-ded23320ffe5#.v6va1kc1w which is using clipPath to do exactly what I need. The issue is that it only seems to animate the stroke and not fill, i think it is related to the e.style.strokeDasharray but i don't really know what that is, and if there is the same thing for fills. Thanks again for all your help.